How do ideal inductors dissipate high frequency noise?
I'm confused about the behavior of ideal inductors. As I understand, inductors provide a high impedance towards high frequency signals, which greatly reduces the noise.
How is the reactive energy lost? I'm confused because what I know about inductors is that they store magnetic energy. When noise goes through an inductor, I'm guessing that the reactive power from the high frequency noise is stored as magnetic energy. In the case of the resistor, it's lost from the electrical circuit as heat, so the downstream components don't see the high current. How does the inductor in this case "lose" the stored reactive power?
This question came because I'm trying to differentiate the behavior of an inductor in a filtering circuit (where we want to dissipate the reactive power) vs a buck converter (where we want to store the reactive power). If the inductor is storing the reactive power, then how is the noise not being introduced back into the circuit?

An ideal inductor does not dissipate noise. It presents a high impedance at high frequencies causing less high frequency current to enter the circuit.

They do not. In a purely reactive LC lowpass filter, the high-frequency energy that the filter filters out just gets sent back to where it came from.
Nonideal inductors can be used to dissipate the energy instead; this is the case with many ferrite beads, which often are made intentionally nonideal.

aha! yes this makes a ton more sense. Is this how chokes work as well? Where they dissipate this energy as heat?

@EErocks "choke" is another word for an inductor. Or do you mean a common-mode choke, which is a set of coupled inductors?

yes sorry that's what I meant, a common-mode choke.
The diagrams on the internet show how the magnetic fields cancel or add depending on whether a choke is differential or common-mode. This is why I had been even more confused because I didn't know how a higher inductance (and thus higher reactance) choke would get rid of the stored energy.

@EErocks Yes, common-mode chokes are frequently designed with lossy ferrites too.

i finally understand, thank you!

There are two perspectives here, and it's not clear which one you're coming from, so I'll describe both.
AC steady state approach:
Suppose there is an ideal AC voltage source.  Connect an inductor to it.  What is the resulting current flow?
At a given frequency, it is \$I = \frac{V}{2 \pi F L}\$, for frequency \$F\$, inductance \$L\$ and voltage (at that frequency) \$V\$.  Current is inversely proportional to inductance, therefore we say a higher inductance "chokes" off current through the circuit.
This remains true if we have a more complicated circuit, with nonzero impedance. suppose we introduce a series resistor: then current (and thus voltage dropped across the resistor) is decreasing sharply for frequencies above \$F_c = \frac{R}{2 \pi L}\$.  Again, we have "choked" current, or voltage or signal, in the circuit.
This is of course again true if we consider energy or power of the signal (which just goes as square of the voltage or current).  When considering power, we also get reactive power, which again is decreasing as L goes up, and which peaks near \$F_c\$ (below which, reactance is less than resistance so there is simply less reactive than real power; and above which, reactance is higher, reducing total [apparent] power draw).  (The special case, for \$R = 0\$, sees reactive power increasing hyperbolically as \$F\$ or \$L\$ approach zero.)
Wave approach:
Suppose there is a wave incident upon a port of given impedance: 
a. If we terminate that port with a resistor \$R = Z_0\$, what is the absorbed and reflected power? 
b. We connect an inductor in series with the resistor.  What is the absorbed and reflected power?
In any case, we calculate the reflection coefficient: \$\Gamma = \frac{Z_L - Z_0}{Z_L + Z_0}\$.
For \$Z_L = R\$, we get \$\Gamma = 0\$, so the reflected power is zero and all incident power is absorbed.  Simple enough.  Conversely if we leave an open or short circuit, all incident power is reflected, in phase (\$\Gamma = 1\$) or opposite (\$\Gamma = -1\$), none absorbed.
For the case \$Z_L = R + j\omega L\$, we have:
$$\Gamma = \frac{\left( R + j\omega L \right) - Z_0}{\left( R + j\omega L \right) + Z_0} = \frac{\left( R - Z_0 + j\omega L\right) \left( R + Z_0 - j\omega L \right)}{\left( R + Z_0 + j\omega L \right)\left( R + Z_0 - j\omega L \right)} = \frac{R^2 - {Z_0}^2 + \omega^2 L^2}{R^2 + 2 R Z_0 +{Z_0}^2 + \omega^2 L^2}$$
which has an asymptote of 1 as \$\omega \rightarrow 1\$, and the resistor matching condition at \$\omega \rightarrow 0\$.
The inductor therefore absorbs no power under these limits, and we reach a similar conclusion.
